# Spring Batch Admin Manager alternative

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Spring Batch Admin Manager implementation is not updated since January 2015.

Is there something else that have to be used instead?
Or should I still use Spring Batch Admin Manager to provide some generic UI for Spring Batch application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean the Spring Batch Admin v1.3.1 release then:

Is there something else? Yes, if your spring batch application is a spring boot variant have a look at https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin and how to configure it checkout http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.1/#getting-started and https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/09/spring-boot-admin-first-official-release/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I meant the Spring Batch Admin 1.3.1 release.

Comment: Welcome, please accept and upvote the answer if it helped you and/or answered your question :)

Comment: This answer might not be relevant to the question as Spring Batch Admin provides the indepth of the jobs, scheduling, status and progress. Talking about the Spring Boot Admin, it provides the detailed view of the application container itself.

Ref: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/461

Answer (score 2):

The [Spring Batch Admin Git Repository](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-batch-admin) claim

> NOTE: This project is being moved to the Spring Attic and is not recommended for new projects. [Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-dataflow) is the recommended replacement for managing and monitoring Spring Batch jobs going forward. You can read more about migrating to Spring Cloud Data Flow [here](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).